# How to use multithreading with websockets?

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket

I am trying to use a websocket (https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) using multithreading. What I want is to keep getting data while my program continues running, however, when I'm doing it like the code below, the server isn't receiving any connections from a client. I was running it before on the main thread and it was working well.

```
async def hello(websocket, path):
    while True:
        data = await websocket.recv()
        print(data)
        await websocket.send(data)


def between_callback():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    ws_server = websockets.serve(hello, '192.168.0.115', 8899)
    
    loop.run_until_complete(ws_server)
    loop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _thread = threading.Thread(target=between_callback)
    _thread.start()

  # Do something in main thread
```

Comment: What does your main thread do? Is it joining the thread?

Comment: @KlausD. It is using the data being received from the websocket to do something else.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the `websockets` sample programs, you seem to be missing one statement, `loop.run_forever()`, which did seem to make a difference (I also changed the IP address to 'localhost' for testing):

```py
def between_callback():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    ws_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8899)

    loop.run_until_complete(ws_server)
    loop.run_forever() # this is missing
    loop.close()
```

**DEMO Program**

Note the updated `hello` function that avoids a *websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: code = 1000 (OK), no reason* exception at termination, which arose, I suspect, due to the termination of the daemon thread.

```py
import websockets
import threading
import asyncio

async def hello(websocket, path):
    async for data in websocket:
        print(f"Received: '{data}'")
        await websocket.send(data)

def between_callback():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    ws_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8899)

    loop.run_until_complete(ws_server)
    loop.run_forever() # this is missing
    loop.close()

async def send_receive_message(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send('This is some text.')
        reply = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"The reply is: '{reply}'")

def client():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(send_receive_message('ws://localhost:8899'))
    loop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # daemon server thread:
    server = threading.Thread(target=between_callback, daemon=True)
    server.start()
    client = threading.Thread(target=client)
    client.start()
    client.join()
```

Prints:

```
Received: 'This is some text.'
The reply is: 'This is some text.'
```

Comment: Isn't `run_until_complete` overwritten by `run_forever` ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "overwritten" but both calls are required if the server is started this way.  More common would be to start the thread whose target is, for example, `def run_server(): asyncio.run(the_server())` and then we have `the_server` as a coroutine:  `async def the_server(): async with websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8899) as ws_server: await asyncio.Future() # run forever`.

Comment: The call `loop.run_until_complete` will take its argument, an instance of class `websockets.legacy.server.Serve` and turn it into a `Future` and then calls `await` on it to wait for its completion. That just creates the actual server, which now has to be run by `loop.run_forever()`.